# Why won't the scheduler execute at the specified time?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I don't understand why my scheduler won't execute the task at the given time when running `php artisan schedule:work`.  Anyone know what the issue could be?  For reference, I'm in the EST timezone.

Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('weekly:winners')->timezone('America/New_York')->weeklyOn(2, '08:53');
}

public function scheduleTimezone()
{
    return 'America/New_York';
}
```

app.php

```
'timezone' => 'UTC'
```

Comment: @PaulT. `app/Console/Kernel.php`

Comment: is the scheduler being ran every minute?